# how to parse same data from one request to other request in jmeter, which is generated by random function?

Tags: jmeter

In my application, email id is same & unique(for each thread) throughout the application.

Now I have use the random function to generate email id on home page i.e. "${__RandomString(5,abcd)}@test.com" so, i can generate the different email-id for different threads. now i want to use the same email id to other pages. how can it possible please suggest.

e.g. :- In home page i use email id as "abcde@test.com" (make sure this email-id is generated by random function), i want to carries the same id on myProfile page too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using only 2 parameters of [__RandomString](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__RandomString) function:

- Random string length
- Chars to use for random string generation

But there is another one: `Name of variable in which to store the result (optional)`

If you amend your function as follows:

```
${__RandomString(5,abcd,email)}@test.com
```

You would be able to refer generated variable as `${email}` or `${__V(email)}`. I would rather go for `__V` option as it's likely that you'll want to add [__threadNum](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) function in conjunction with __RandomString to bind variable to current thread number.

See [How to Use JMeter Functions](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii) posts series for more information on various JMeter functions and their best use cases.